# Wordpress custom post + custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Is there is a way to place custom fields inside of a custom post in a Wordpress 3.0 template? I looked around for a while and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be able to help:

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use Custom Field Template plugin. It's much easier than hard coded meta boxes: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/